# Three way interactions for generalized linear mixed effects model and interpretation of post hoc comparisons

Tags: glmm, post-hoc, longitudinal-data-analysis

The data I am working on has three categorical variables and one continuous variable. I am using a generalized mixed effects model across four time points before and after administering a drug. The drug responses are modeled as:

y ~ A * B * C + (1+interaction(B*C)|Subject)

where y is the drug response; A is the condition of the subject(two conditions disease and control); B is before or after treatment(two levels) and C is 4 time points at each level of B. Below is what I am struggling with:

a) Do I use one covariate with 8 time points(B has before and after treatment and C has 4 time points each) or include both the covariates?

b) Is it a correct approach to give a random slope for the interaction of B and C when it is significant compared to the model in which random slope is not given?

c) In addition to comparing a1 vs a2 in b1 c1 and so on, I am also interested to look at the differences across interactions of two factors in the third factor. For instance, a significant difference between a1 vs a2 across b1 vs b2 in c1 and so on. I am using emmeans for example emmeans(model, ~A*B|C) which gives a result as a1-a2 b1-b2 c1 0.034 but I am not sure how to interpret it.

d) Finally, I am using a Dunnett correction since I am comparing control to other levels, I am not sure how to correct for multiple comparisons focussed towards multiple hypothesis as mentioned above

I apologize for the number of questions, but I've been very confused with the ambiguous explanations I came across so far